# Getting the size of my list is crashing my program

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

It's only a one line file.

When I call .size() with something else (like appending it to a string of spaces), it spits out something, so why would it would crash when I call the function alone?

```
int pos =0;
List<List<String>> mine = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
while((nextLine = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
    mine.add(pos,new ArrayList <String>());
    for (String token : nextLine.split(",")) {

        //get next token and store it in the list
        mine.get(pos).add(token); 
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,mine.size() + " " + mine.get(pos).size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " " + mine.get(pos).size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //doesn't crash here

    //  mine_end= mine.get(pos).size(); //crash here

    pos ++;
}
```

Here is the latest stack trace of errors:

07-17 15:52:44.987: E/wpa_supplicant(29035): Ongoing Scan action...
07-17 15:52:46.989: E/wpa_supplicant(29035): Ongoing Scan action...
07-17 15:52:48.991: E/wpa_supplicant(29035): Ongoing Scan action...
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:221)
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:284)
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection.MainActivity.match(MainActivity.java:137)
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection.MainActivity.access$2(MainActivity.java:91)
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection.MainActivity$2$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:383)
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
07-17 15:52:49.061: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 15:52:49.071: E/(306): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the crash? Where is mine_end defined?

Comment: What is the stack trace? My guess is List at pos is null. For example if pos is '5', there is no list at index '5' which thrwos NullPointerException.

Comment: can you indent the code properly?

Comment: mine_end is defined right before pos. I have never used stack trace , will google how to get that working

Comment: Use this to view Logcat and post here all the error lines you get there: http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html

Comment: @user1526556 : What data type is `mine_end`?

Comment: integer type, I don't need to use mine_end, IF I simply do a Toast with mine.get(pos).size() alone , it will still crash

Comment: @user1526556 : There's nothing in that logcat output that would indicate any error related to `mine.get(pos).size()`. You posted the wrong bit of the logcat.

Comment: The error in the StackTrace that you posted refers to the fact that you are (or were) using the `mine.get(pos).size()` directly, which resulted this method being called: `Toast.makeText(android.content.Context, int, int)`. However, you really wanted the `(Context, String, int)` version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was something completely unrelated. I guess I shouldn't use Toast messages to debug.  In this case, it affected the timing and led me to believe that the .size() was causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite likely that `mine.get(pos)` is returning `null`, hence a `NullPointerException` occurs. Make sure that you've initialized each `pos` position in the list.

Comment: IF I add this line right after mine.get(pos).add(token), it will crash. I just added a token (which doesn't crash) pwhich doesn't make sense why it would be returning null

Comment: @Oscar Lopez, if what you said was true, then it would crush in the for loop, even before where he says it crashes.

Comment: We can't tell for sure until OP posts the exact error produced at the crash site